# undefined method `longitude=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm newbie in RoR. I program in Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2
In my model:

```
class SharedInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :shared_info_type_id, :severity_id, :source_info_id, :created_date
end
```

In my controller:

```
@sharedinfo = SharedInfo.new(params[:shareinfo])
@sharedInfo.longitude = params[:longitude][:value]
@sharedInfo.latitude = params[:latitude][:value]
@sharedInfo.save
```

When it excute it. The browser lead the the error: "undefined method `longitude=' for nil:NilClass"
Does anyone help me to resolve this problem?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo here. Ruby is case sensitive. You initialize `@sharedinfo` but later use `@sharedInfo`.

Fix it by using a capital `I` in the first line, too:

```
@sharedInfo = SharedInfo.new(params[:shareinfo])
```

Comment: CamelCase is uncommon in ruby, I suggest naming the variable `@shared_info`

Answer (score 0):

I think that, you should use '_' in params hash.

```
@shared_info = SharedInfo.new params[:shared_info]
```